# Python MySQL date time format

Tags: python, mysql

I have a model:

```
class errors(models.Model):
    date           = models.DateTimeField()
    msg            = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I simply cannot get the date format right when inserting. I do

```
msg = "error" 
date = datetime.datetime.now()

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cmt_errors('date', 'msg') VALUES (%s, %s)", (date, msg))
```

How should I format date so I don't get a syntax error? I am, btw, able to do a select so I've got the tables imported, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not put single-quotes around the column names:

```
"INSERT INTO cmt_errors(date, msg) VALUES (%s, %s)"
```

Comment: DOH! Thank-you! Solves my problem. I had been staring myself blind.